# How to select (one or multiple) line in a text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textarea` with multiple lines. My purpose is to select a line ( with a click or some combo keys). The `textarea` is:

```
<textarea id="table" disabled ></textarea>
```

And I put inside the `textarea` some default value. I tried with:

```
$('#table').on('click',function());
```

But I don't know how to select lines. Can anyone can help me?

Comment: So you do not have anything inside `function(){ }` yet??

Comment: Disabled elements don't fire mouse events

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, a textarea only lets you select the whole text:

```
$('#table')[0].select();
$('#table').on('click', function() { this.select() });
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp for the full API of the textarea

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight just some words, you can use this

```
<script>
  $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
    words: ['Lorem ipsum', 'vulputate']
  });
</script>
```

Check [this](http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/) for more info. It is an interesting plug-in. In a textarea, just as manuBriot mentioned, you select the entire text. Depending on resolution, a line could contain more or less words.